# Invalid Hook Call - GetStreamChat API

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, getstream-io

Trying to install the GetStreamChat React JS API but getting:
`Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

I followed the debug guide from `https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html`but still unable to figure it out.

The guide lists 3 commons causes but I went through all of them.

**Common Cause 1: Mismatching Versions of React and React DOM?**

I am using `react-dom@16.13.1`

**Common cause 2: Breaking the Rules of Hooks?**
This is how I'm implementing the functional component:

`chatbox.js` -> this is straight copied and pasted from their API tutorial guide. It works in an app all by itself.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Chat, Channel, ChannelHeader, Window } from 'stream-chat-react';
import { MessageList, MessageInput, MessageLivestream } from 'stream-chat-react';
import { MessageInputSmall, Thread } from 'stream-chat-react';
import { StreamChat } from 'stream-chat';

import 'stream-chat-react/dist/css/index.css';

const chatClient = new StreamChat('XYZ');
const userToken = 'XYZ';

chatClient.setUser(
    {
        id: 'crimson-rice-9',
        name: 'Crimson rice',
        image: 'https://getstream.io/random_png/?id=crimson-rice-9&name=Crimson+rice'
    },
    userToken,
);

const channel = chatClient.channel('livestream', 'spacex', {
    image: 'image here',
    name: 'Bruh Goes Boi',
});

const ChatBox = () => (

    <Chat client={chatClient} theme={'livestream dark'}>
        <Channel channel={channel} Message={MessageLivestream}>
            <Window hideOnThread>
                <ChannelHeader live />
                <MessageList />
                <MessageInput Input={MessageInputSmall} focus />
            </Window>
            <Thread fullWidth />
        </Channel>
    </Chat>
);

export default ChatBox;
```

`testscreen2.js`

```
import ChatBox from "../Chat/ChatBox"
require('react-dom');
window.React2 = require('react');
console.log(window.React1 === window.React2);


const TestPage2 = () => {

    return (

        <div>
            <p>Why you not work</p>
            <ChatBox/>
        </div>
    )

}

export default TestPage2
```

**Common Cause 3: Duplicate React**
Running `npm ls react` produces:

```
starter-template@1.0.0 /Users/michaelninh/WebstormProjects/Shuriken
└─┬ stream-chat-react@2.2.0
  └─┬ react-file-utils@0.3.15
    └─┬ react-file-icon@0.2.0
      └── react@16.13.1
```

Since I don't have multiple reacts showing, does this mean I only have one react copy? However when I do the other suggested test, it **produces false** which the guide says that I have two React copies:

```
// Add this in node_modules/react-dom/index.js
window.React1 = require('react');

// Add this in your component file
require('react-dom');
window.React2 = require('react');
console.log(window.React1 === window.React2);

PRODUCES FALSE
```

If I do have multiple react copies, I am unsure how to debug since I'm a beginner at this.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. I installed the package in my project packages folder instead of the the client packages.